# With Django, how can I ensure manage commands have custom logging?

Tags: python, django, logging

**Scenario**

I want to ensure (guarantee) that all manage command invocations generate logs to a custom location, based on the name; e.g. the command appends to a file named for the command:

> $ bin/django changepassword ...
>
> $ ls /var/log/django/changepassword.log
>
> $ bin/django shell
>
> $ ls /var/log/django/shell.log

**Options**

I have a custom logging configuration which I'm registering in settings.py, but that's not the place I'd expect to get such custom behavior.

Monkey patch something? But what, and where?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go with a logger which is installed globally; and then enable it only when a manage command was run from the command-line.

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from logging.handlers import WatchedFileHandler
from logging import Handler, getLogger

LOG = getLogger(__name__)


class ManageCommandLogger(Handler):
    """
    A logger which only enables when you're running manage commands.
    """
    _instance = None

    def __init__(self, filename, mode='a', encoding=None, delay=0):
        self._kwargs = dict(filename=filename, mode=mode, encoding=encoding, delay=delay)
        self._handler = None
        super(ManageCommandLogger, self).__init__()
        self.__class__._instance = self

    @classmethod
    def enable(cls, name, path=None):
        self = cls._instance
        if self._handler:
            return
        if not path:
            self._kwargs['filename'] %= name
        else:
            self._kwargs['filename'] = path
        self._handler = WatchedFileHandler(**self._kwargs)
        self._handler.setFormatter(self.formatter)
        self._handler.level = self.level
        LOG.info("command logging enabled to %s", self._kwargs['filename'])

    def handle(self, record):
        if not self._handler:
            return
        return super(ManageCommandLogger, self).handle(record)

    def emit(self, record):
        if not self._handler:
            return
        self._handler.emit(record)


def _patch_run_from_argv(self, *args, **kwargs):
    name = args[0][1]
    ManageCommandLogger.enable(name)
    return self._run_from_argv(*args, **kwargs)


BaseCommand._run_from_argv = BaseCommand.run_from_argv
BaseCommand.run_from_argv = _patch_run_from_argv
```